# Fmincon calls SNOPT

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I've started to use Tomlab SNOPT on Matlab. I've followed the quick guide attached to it, but now I've noticed that also using fmincon (also with interior-point algorithm) calls the snopt solver. Is it normal? How to disable it?

Comment: It is possible that that package includes a function that is also called `fmincon`. Whether that's intentional or not I cannot tell; if so, it is a consequence of the fact that Matlab lacks namespaces.

Comment: @A.Donda: Matlab does have a form of namespaces, but only within object-oriented programming: [packages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the package includes a function called fmincon.
Reading carefully the startup log I found:

```
Warning - optimization toolbox drop-in replacements
Remove tomlab\optim from path to disable
```

So problem solved, it is a new fmincon function that on purpose adapt the standard fmincon call to the snopt solver.